# can't add Li Dynamically using Jquery for carousel

Tags: jquery, html

I am using Elastislide carousel plugin and adding images to it dynamically from a table which has the path to images. Now I am using jQuery to append list item to the Elastislide's unordered list.

The problem is, in Elastislide's CSS, display is set to none (I checked it in CSS file) and when they are rendered they are displayed correctly.

When I add the list items dynamically they are not displayed. I'm guessing their CSS still
displays to none.

Here is the code I used to append to list items.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('#aspnetGridView tr').each(function () {
         if (!this.rowIndex) return; // skip first row
         var path = this.cells[0].innerHTML;
         alert(path);
         $('#rack1 #carousel').append('<li><a href="#"><img src="'+ path +'" alt="image03" /></a></li>');
    });
});
```

And here is the place where where the static list items are added.

```
<div id="rack1"><ul id="carousel"  class="elastislide-list">
<li><a href="#"><img src="images/bookCover/java2.jpg" alt="image05" /></a></li></ul></div>
```

And this is how the static items in carousel are displayed after rendering of page.
I checked this using firebug.

```
<li style="width: 33.2418%; max-width: 65px; max-height: 76px;"><a href="#"><img src="images/bookCover/aspnetDesign.jpg"></a>
```

Please help me, tell me where I am doing something wrong.  Is it the positioning of using JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the carousel you're using is anything like I've seen in a few other plugins, the problem is actually a cache issue. When the page loads, the plugin creates an in-memory array of all the items it needs to cycle through, and then uses those to determine what to show. So, when you add new items to the markup, they're not included in the array of "slides" the plugin knows about, since they weren't part of the DOM when it was initialized.

I will amend this after I check the documentation for the plugin you're using, but hopefully this lets you troubleshoot a few things in the meanwhile.

**EDIT:**

Looks like you're just missing one (admittedly important) step. You need to call `.add()` after appending the item(s). So, add this:

```
$('#rack1 #carousel').add();
```

and you should be good-to-go (reference: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/09/12/elastislide-responsive-carousel/).

Comment: Well, added the    $('#carousel').elastislide() at end of each append. and now the images are displayed but they are small.It seems like Css is not set to them.. Any thoughts?

Comment: @designerNProgrammer Can you create a jsFiddle or similar that demonstrates the issue? Otherwise, I assume you just need to apply a width to the images (`width:100%` via a `style` attribute or CSS class) to make them fill the parent `<div>`.

Comment: yeah Man thanks, it worked.. Actually i forgot to add this after the add $('#carousel').elastislide();  Thanks a Bunch..